# Single ticket from EDI to Leuchars (St Andrews)?

Tags: scotland, edi

The usual route from EDI airport to St Andrews is:

- Take the tram to Edinburgh Gateway/Haymarket station
- Take any train to Leuchars
- (Optionally: Take any bus 99x to St Andrews.)

Is it possible to do this on a single ticket, or does it really require three different ones?  (Each step seems to be run by a different entity with its own ticket machines.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do it on a single ticket as each of the operators is a different entity.

Alternatively you could take a Stagecoach bus 747 from Edinburgh Airport to Halbeath Park & Ride in Fife then change to a Stagecoach X24 bus to St Andrews bus station, which as Willeke suggested can be booked on a single ticket (a "Fife dayrider Plus").

[Travelinescotland](https://www.travelinescotland.com) is a useful site for planning journeys.

Comment: It seems like it, it's called a "Fife dayrider Plus" (see [Stagecoach](https://www.stagecoachbus.com) website).

Comment: I feel that more information is needed here. For example, ordinary UK train tickets are valid on routes that use trains run by multiple companies (e.g., when I visit my parents I buy one ticket and use it on trains run by Cross Country and Northern Rail). So "each of the operators is a different entity" isn't a reason. Further, one can buy "plus bus" versions of train tickets to certain cities, which are valid for train travel to that city, along with bus travel within it. I see you live in Edinburgh, so I'm not disputing your claim that multiple tickets are required -- just your justification

Comment: For the OP's chosen route the tram is operated by [Edinburgh Trams](http://edinburghtrams.com), the train from Edinburgh Gateway or Haymarket to Leuchars is operated by [Scotrail](https://www.scotrail.co.uk) and the bus from Leuchars to St Andrews is operated by [Stagecoach](https://www.stagecoachbus.com). Unfortunately in this case there is no single ticket that covers these three modes of transport and operators on this particular route.

Comment: There is the [RailBus](https://www.scotrail.co.uk/offers/travel-passes/rail-and-bus) ticket which can combine the rail travel to Leuchars and bus to St Andrews. Doesn't include the tram though

Answer (score 7):

If this is a regular daily journey can be done with a single ticket for the train and buses, unfortunately it doesn't include the Edinburgh trams. It's a [rail+bus OneTicket](https://www.one-ticket.co.uk/rail-plus-bus-tickets) which is a zonal season ticket available in weekly, monthly or annual versions.

It is also possible to buy a train ticket to "St Andrews Bus" which gives you a train journey to Leuchers and a bus journey to St Andrews. You can then buy a [plus bus add on ticket for within Edinburgh](http://www.plusbus.info/edinburgh) including the tram (excluding the airport). However these would need to be done before getting to the station, e.g. the day before.

Comment: Note there are also tickets to/from "EDB APT BUS/TRAM", but there are no fares available from there to "St Andrews Bus".

Answer (score 2):

Contra the other answers, the national rail ticket machines will sell a ticket from Leuchars to Edinburgh Airport that allows using the tram.  When you are controlled, on the tram, you get a free transfer tram ticket.

For the return trip, there's a train ticket machine near the M & S at EDI.